# Excel Macro to create a report file

Tags: excel, file-io, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets, Report and Data.  I want to write a section of the Report tab out to a new workbook file (print range named "Roster") and retain the formatting, print settings, etc.

Below is the macro I have so far - it works but writes the whole Report tab to the file, not just the roster section, and it loses the print range which would be useful for the recipient of the resulting file.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
  Dim Output As Workbook
  Dim FileName As String


  'This part updates the roster - grabs the next
  'roster value and move it to A1, thus updating the report

  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("A1").Select

 'Now we write the Report worksheet to a new file using
 'the custom filename in cell AA1

  Set Output = Workbooks.Add
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Cells.Copy

  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
  Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

  FileName = Range("AA1").Value

  Output.SaveAs FileName
  Output.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is copying the whole Report tab because of the line

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Cells.Copy
```

The .Cells gets all the cells of a worksheet. To get a portion you could try something like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Range(FirstCell, LastCell).Copy
```

where FirstCell and LastCell are the start and end of the range you want to copy. To duplicate the print area you could try something like

```
DestinationSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = OriginalSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea
```

Hope that helps